# How do I Configure Unity to use constructor injection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

In my MVC 5 app I am  using Unity.  Constructor injection is working fine as expected.  Suppose I have a class which is not a controller and I have this setup for constructor injection, how can I configure Unity (code not xml) to tell it to use constructor injection when I new up an instance of my class.  Is this possible?

My class is below:

```
public class Thing
{
    private readonly IAuthorisationService _authorisationService;

    public Thing()
    {

    }

    public Thing(IAuthorisationService authorisationService)
    {
        _authorisationService = authorisationService;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        var result = _authorisationService.IsAdmin(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

So I am missing the bit where I tell unity to take over and inject when I new up a Thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming default Unity configuration all classes auto-registered with Unity, so the only thing you need is to call `Resolve` for your class on container.

```
var theThing = container.Resolve<Thing>();
```

Note that usually you get it happen magically by having dependency on `Thing` in your other classes (i.e. controllers).

If you need to create multiple instances of `Thing` - take dependency on `Func<Thing>` instead (which is also auto-registered and provides way to create instances resolved by container in the way you'd use `new`).

```
 public MyController(Func<Thing> thingCreator)
 {
     var manyThings = Enumerable.Range(0, 9001).Select(()=> thingCreator());
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Ok I'm very confused now.  I tried this and it worked but when I run it again it now doesn't work.  See updated code above.

Comment: @DaveAmour if you have updates to *question* edit them in the question. Your suggested edit does not belong to answer... Also "does_not_work" is not really explanation of a problem. Side note: I'd strongly recommend writing code you have as unit test (or in command line app) and getting it working first there as it generally much easier to debug smaller pieces of code.

Comment: Sorry Alexei - I must be stupid as I find the SO UI difficult to use.  How do I show you more code in response to a comment?  I don't want to change the question but reply to your answer - there is not enough room in these comment boxes.  What is the right way to do this?

Comment: @DaveAmour Yes, you can't put more that half line of code in comments and keep it readable. This is mostly intentional on SO as comments for clarification. Updating question OR asking new question are common options. Asking separate question with standalone sample (preferably [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in your case seem quite reasonable.

Comment: What if I am having conversations with 3 people and I want to update my question to reflect what we are discussing then that won't work very well and spawning new questions constantly rather than having a conversation seems a bit ridiculous to me.

Comment: I have managed to get this working now.  I did it with: var theThing = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Thing>();  Does that seem the right way to do it?

Comment: @DaveAmour SO comments is not appropriate place for policy discussion - please consider asking policy question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ (as described on http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @DaveAmour While I personally dislike service locator pattern if it works for you than it is fine.

Comment: Why does everyone have to be so irritating on here?  Can't you just chill out and be nice instead of being the policy police all the time!  Oh sorry should this have gone in the insults discussion area?